# Not able to connect to external monitor using Thinkpad Thunderbolt docking station

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, ventura

I am trying to connect my laptop, MacBook Pro (2019) Ventura 13.4, to my external monitor using a ThinkPad Thunderbolt 4 docking station. The external monitor is connected to the docking station using an HDMI cable and the MacBook is connected to the docking station using a Thunderbolt 3 cable.

I see the white light on my docking station and my laptop is charging so it doesn't seem like an issue with the docking station.

However, it fails to detect the external monitor.  I hear the beep sound and my laptop monitor freezes for a few seconds when I connect the docking station to my laptop, however, after that nothing.

Also, I have no issues connecting my MacBook Air (2019) Ventura 31.1 to the same external monitor using the same docking station and the same USB-C cable.

I can connect to an external monitor using a HDMI to USB-C converter to my MacBook Pro.

[image: The back of the ThinkPad Thunderbolt 4 docking station showing the different ports]

Comment: Are you using the same cable going from the Mac to the dock in both instances (Air and Pro)?  Have you tried a different TB port on the Pro?  What if you bypass the dock and connect the monitor directly to the Pro?

Comment: yes, same cable. and I tried all the four ports on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: And bypassing the dock altogether?

Comment: @Allan that works. if I use dongle in connect HDMI directly.

Comment: You might have a compatibility   issue with the dock.  Can you post an [edit] with these new details plus how you you’re connecting from the dock to the monitor (i.e. HDMI to HDMI, DisplayPort to HDMI, etc.)

Comment: @Allan updated, monitor is connect using HDMI to docking station.

Comment: If possible (if the dock and your monitor supports it), go from DisplayPort to DisplayPort; don’t convert to HDMI.  This will reduce the complexity and give you a more reliable signal.

Comment: Monitor has HDMI only, which goes to docking station and from docking station to MacBook it's usb-c.  There is not DisplayPort.

Comment: So, to clarify, dock has HDMI and is connected  to monitor’s HDMI

Comment: @Allan yes,  I added picture so it's more clean. and dock has usb-c as well. the one with laptop and thunderbolt icon, it's connect to my bankbook.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably be sure I use a [new thunderbolt 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M6S81CM) or ideally future proof yourself with an [OWC Thunderbolt 4 cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09KTB326W) for that dock instead of a USB cable.

[There are still enough differences between USB 4 and Thunderbolt 4](https://www.tomsguide.com/features/thunderbolt-4-vs-usb4-whats-the-difference) that it's worth the cost and hopefully you can balance where you buy the cable with a place that offers either advice or returns that mean the investment won't be for nothing. I'm assuming you've already exhausted support from the vendor of the dock or can't use that for reasons.

Comment: Nice to know the difference.  my cable is thunderbolt 3. I see a thunderbolt icon and 3 digit on it. based on connector I thought it's usb-c.

Comment: @GaurangShah It's quite painful to be clear what connector type vs what data rating and internal cabling exists. Thunderbolt uses the same connector now as USB-C and mini DisplayPort in the past. Even if your cable is the correct type - another cable is always something I check as it's a likely failure point and usually the cheapest to test in terms of time and expense.